# Adafruit_BBIO.ADC.setup() on ubuntu 16.04.1 error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, beagleboneblack, adafruit

I installed the Adafruit_BBIO module on my BBB (I downloaded it from github and installed manually).
The GPIO works just fine but when I try to use the ADC I get an error as follows:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC  
ADC.setup()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Unable to setup ADC system. Possible causes are: 
- A cape with a conflicting pin mapping is loaded 
- A device tree object is loaded that uses the same name for a fragment: helper
```

I couldn't find an answer for this problem.
Should I just use an older version of ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.
You can fine the solution here: https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/127#issuecomment-266049880

In short, all you need to do is:

```
echo cape-universaln > /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
```