# Adafruit_BBIO.ADC.setup() error on Debian 9.2

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, adafruit

While my question is similar to [Adafruit_BBIO.ADC.setup() on ubuntu 16.04.1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028021/adafruit-bbio-adc-setup-on-ubuntu-16-04-1-error), the answer provided in that question does not solve my problem.

I'm running the below Python script on a Beaglebone Black.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
ADC.setup()

#read returns values 0-1.0 
value = ADC.read("P8_8")
```

My board is set up so that I have a 3.3V output running through a voltage divider, and I'm measuring the voltage at a point in the divider where it should read 1.65V.  However, when I run the above code, I get the following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/cloud9/examples/LED_flash/adc_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    ADC.setup()
RuntimeError: Unable to setup ADC system. Possible causes are:
  - A cape with a conflicting pin mapping is loaded
  - A device tree object is loaded that uses the same name for a fragment: helper
```

I've updated Adafruit_BBIO to the most recent version (1.1.1) and the error persists.  I've also tried following [a suggestion from here](https://www.mail-archive.com/beagleboard@googlegroups.com/msg34780.html), which I got to from [this Github listing](https://gist.github.com/pdp7/540d5e33ed0e4cb307e7) of the same problem as a bug sometime last year.  When I ran the code there, I got the following result.

```
sudo sh -c "echo BB-ADC' > /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots"
bash: /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots: Permission denied
```

So, I'm kinda perplexed and would love to have an idea of where to go next.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Robert Nelson on the Beaglebone Black forums.

The /boot/uEnv.txt file was modified and needed to be changed such that the following lines were present as written below.

```
enable_uboot_overlays=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1
```